# Modal window content displays in the main window

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm new to web development and for now, I'm trying just to make a simple modal window on my site. 
I use basic code from [here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/reveal.html)

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <h2 id="modalTitle">Awesome. I have it.</h2>
  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

However, it doesn't do what it does in the example page (i.e. it should display only the link Click Me For A Modal and everything else in the modal after the click). Instead, it displays everything in the main window:

What am I doing wrong and how to make it work as supposed? Thank you.

Comment: It displays in the main window:

Click Me For A Modal
Awesome. I have it.
Your couch. It is mine.

I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!

×

Comment: Have you included the related foundation CSS/JS file?

Comment: Ok, that is the issue. Do you have in mind a good guide on how to include them in Wordpress? Thank you!